# Error - SpriteFont not implemented

Tags: c#, monogame, spritefont

I'm trying to draw text in a Monogame program. I want to use a SpriteFont to do it, but I get the following error when trying to load the SpriteFont.

```
//Here I try to load the SpriteFont
//It is kept in the "Content/fonts" folder, with "Content" as the Content.RootDirectory
Font = Content.Load<SpriteFont>("fonts/SpriteFont1");

//I then get this error
An unhandled exception of type 'System.NotImplementedException' occurred in MonoGame.Framework.dll
Additional information: The method or operation is not implemented.
```

The SpriteFont1 build action is set to "Content" with Copy To Output Directory as "Copy Always". The SpriteFont1.xnb file is in the Content folder, with the same settings. How can I fix the error so that I can load the SpriteFont?

Comment: A method is not implemented.  This could be in the Mono library.  The stack trace will show which method.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simple fix. Following the stack trace (thanks to Richard Schneider), I found that the SpriteFont1.xnb file needed to be in the same folder as the actual .SpriteFont file.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, only .xnb file is needed as it is compiled from the .SpriteFont, so you should copy only the .xnb file to the Content folder.

The `NotImplementedException` is because the `LoadContent` is not implemented to load .SpriteFont file directly. (Tested in MonoGame 3.5)